# make can not locate an installed library

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal

I have installed hdf5 in /usr/local/hdf5. However, when I try to install another library, caffe, the make file doesn't seem to be able to locate hdf5. How should I fix this? I am using a mac.

```
(Zahraa1)mass-MacBook-Pro:caffe mas$ make pycaffe -j8
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
#include "hdf5.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp:13:10: fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
#include "hdf5.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o] Error 1
src/caffe/net.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
#include "hdf5.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/net.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the directory with hdfs5.h in your include path. There are different ways to do it depending on your Makefile (INCLUDEPATH, CXXFLAGS or so).